# Criar input do type=submit dentro do código do calendário

Tags: php, html, mysql

Código do calendário com checkboxes em cada dia do mês para marcar as refeições:

```
<?php

# PHP Calendar (version 2.3), written by Keith Devens

function generate_calendar($year, $month, $days = array(), $day_name_length = 3, $month_href = NULL, $first_day = 0, $pn = array()){
    $first_of_month = gmmktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    #remember that mktime will automatically correct if invalid dates are entered
    # for instance, mktime(0,0,0,12,32,1997) will be the date for Jan 1, 1998
    # this provides a built in "rounding" feature to generate_calendar()

    $day_names = array(); #generate all the day names according to the current locale
    for($n=0,$t=(3+$first_day)*86400; $n<7; $n++,$t+=86400) #January 4, 1970 was a Sunday
        $day_names[$n] = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A',$t)); #%A means full textual day name

        $mes_pt = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');

    list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',gmstrftime('%m,%Y,%B,%w',$first_of_month));
    $weekday = ($weekday + 7 - $first_day) % 7; #adjust for $first_day
    //$title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($month_name)).'&nbsp;'.$year;  #note that some locales don't capitalize month and day names

    $title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($mes_pt[(int)$month])).'&nbsp;'.$year;

    #Begin calendar. Uses a real <caption>. See http://diveintomark.org/archives/2002/07/03
    @list($p, $pl) = each($pn); @list($n, $nl) = each($pn); #previous and next links, if applicable
    if($p) $p = '<span class="calendar-prev">'.($pl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($pl).'">'.$p.'</a>' : $p).'</span>&nbsp;';
    if($n) $n = '&nbsp;<span class="calendar-next">'.($nl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($nl).'">'.$n.'</a>' : $n).'</span>';
    $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'."\n".
        '<caption class="calendar-month"><h1><center><strong>'.$p.($month_href ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($month_href).'">'.$title.'</a>' : $title).$n."</strong></center></h1></caption>\n<tr>";

    if($day_name_length){ #if the day names should be shown ($day_name_length > 0)
        #if day_name_length is >3, the full name of the day will be printed
        //foreach($day_names as $d)
            //$calendar .= '<th abbr="'.htmlentities($d).'">'.htmlentities($day_name_length < 4 ? substr($d,0,$day_name_length) : $d).'</th>';

            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Domingo</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Segunda</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Terça</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quarta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quinta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sexta</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sábado</th>";

        $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
    }

    if($weekday > 0) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.$weekday.'">&nbsp;</td>'; #initial 'empty' days
    for($day=1,$days_in_month=gmdate('t',$first_of_month); $day<=$days_in_month; $day++,$weekday++){
        if($weekday == 7){
            $weekday   = 0; #start a new week
            $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
        }
        if(isset($days[$day]) and is_array($days[$day])){
            @list($link, $classes, $content) = $days[$day];
            if(is_null($content))  $content  = $day;
            $calendar .= '<td'.($classes ? ' class="'.htmlspecialchars($classes).'">' : '>').
                ($link ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($link).'">'.$content.'</a>' : $content).'</td>';
        }
        else 

        $calendar .= "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=''><center><font size='2px'/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][dia]' value=$day> $day <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq. Almoço'> Peq. Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço'> Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço Dieta'> Almoço (Dieta)<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche'> Lanche<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoE]' value='Jantar'> Jantar<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoF]' value='Jantar Dieta'> Jantar (Dieta)</font></center></td>";

    }

    if($weekday != 7) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.(7-$weekday).'">&nbsp;

    </td>'; #remaining "empty" days

    return $calendar."</tr>\n</table>\n";


}

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

    $dates = date('Y/m/d');
    $hoje = getdate(strtotime($dates)); 


    //Monta o calendário
    if(isset($_POST["data"])){

        list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode('/', $_POST["data"]);
        echo generate_calendar($ano,$mes,$dia);

    }   else {

        echo generate_calendar($hoje["year"], $hoje["mon"], $hoje["mday"]);
    }
?>
```

Tenho este código para inserir na tabela da base de dados e sei que está a funcionar:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){
    $string = implode(' ', $selected);
    $sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES('$string')";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}
}
}
?>
```

O meu problema é que não consigo inserir na base de dados os `value` da checkbox seleccionadas no calendário.

Uma das Soluções seria esta:

```
for($day=1,$days_in_month=gmdate('t',$first_of_month); $day<=$days_in_month; $day++,$weekday++){
        if($weekday == 7){
            $weekday   = 0; #start a new week
            $calendar .= "<form action='' method='POST'></tr>\n<tr>";

return $calendar."<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Marcar'>
       </form></tr>\n</table>\n";
```

Nesta solução acrescento o `<form action='' method='POST'>` e `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Marcar'>`como mostro no código acima.

Comment: Já resolvi o meu problema

Comment: Posta a solução! É uma boa para comunidade.

Comment: @Fabiano Monteiro, postei a solução que encontrei mas optei pela sua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só montar o formulário! Pelo seu condigo de inserção, todos os dados entrariam na mesma tupla.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registo Refeições</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //////////////////////////
            $(function() {
                $( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                });
            });
        ////////////////
        })
    </script>

    <form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="text" name="data" id="date_picker">  
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php

# PHP Calendar (version 2.3), written by Keith Devens

function generate_calendar($year, $month, $days = array(), $day_name_length = 3, $month_href = NULL, $first_day = 0, $pn = array()){
    $first_of_month = gmmktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    #remember that mktime will automatically correct if invalid dates are entered
    # for instance, mktime(0,0,0,12,32,1997) will be the date for Jan 1, 1998
    # this provides a built in "rounding" feature to generate_calendar()

    $day_names = array(); #generate all the day names according to the current locale
    for($n=0,$t=(3+$first_day)*86400; $n<7; $n++,$t+=86400) #January 4, 1970 was a Sunday
        $day_names[$n] = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A',$t)); #%A means full textual day name

        $mes_pt = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');

    list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',gmstrftime('%m,%Y,%B,%w',$first_of_month));
    $weekday = ($weekday + 7 - $first_day) % 7; #adjust for $first_day
    //$title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($month_name)).'&nbsp;'.$year;  #note that some locales don't capitalize month and day names

    $title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($mes_pt[(int)$month])).'&nbsp;'.$year;

    #Begin calendar. Uses a real <caption>. See http://diveintomark.org/archives/2002/07/03
    @list($p, $pl) = each($pn); @list($n, $nl) = each($pn); #previous and next links, if applicable
    if($p) $p = '<span class="calendar-prev">'.($pl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($pl).'">'.$p.'</a>' : $p).'</span>&nbsp;';
    if($n) $n = '&nbsp;<span class="calendar-next">'.($nl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($nl).'">'.$n.'</a>' : $n).'</span>';
    $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'."\n".
        '<caption class="calendar-month">'.$p.($month_href ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($month_href).'">'.$title.'</a>' : $title).$n."</caption>\n<tr>";

    if($day_name_length){ #if the day names should be shown ($day_name_length > 0)
        #if day_name_length is >3, the full name of the day will be printed
        //foreach($day_names as $d)
            //$calendar .= '<th abbr="'.htmlentities($d).'">'.htmlentities($day_name_length < 4 ? substr($d,0,$day_name_length) : $d).'</th>';

            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Domingo</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Segunda</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Terça</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quarta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quinta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sexta</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sábado</th>";

        $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
    }

    if($weekday > 0) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.$weekday.'">&nbsp;</td>'; #initial 'empty' days
    for($day=1,$days_in_month=gmdate('t',$first_of_month); $day<=$days_in_month; $day++,$weekday++){
        if($weekday == 7){
            $weekday   = 0; #start a new week
            $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
        }
        if(isset($days[$day]) and is_array($days[$day])){
            @list($link, $classes, $content) = $days[$day];
            if(is_null($content))  $content  = $day;
            $calendar .= '<td'.($classes ? ' class="'.htmlspecialchars($classes).'">' : '>').
                ($link ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($link).'">'.$content.'</a>' : $content).'</td>';
        }
        else 

        $calendar .= "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=''><center><font size='2px'/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][dia]' value=$day> $day <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq. Almoço'> Peq. Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço'> Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço Dieta'> Almoço (Dieta)<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche'> Lanche<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoE]' value='Jantar'> Jantar<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoF]' value='Jantar Dieta'> Jantar (Dieta)</font></center></td>";

    }
    if($weekday != 7) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.(7-$weekday).'">&nbsp;

    </td>'; #remaining "empty" days

    return $calendar."</tr>\n</table>\n";
}

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

    $dates = date('Y/m/d');
    $hoje = getdate(strtotime($dates)); 


    //Monta o calendário
    if(isset($_POST["data"])){
?>    
        <form name="form2" id="mainForm2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">    
            <?php
                list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode('/', $_POST["data"]);
                echo generate_calendar($ano,$mes,$dia);
            ?>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <form name="form3" id="mainForm3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
            <?php  echo generate_calendar($hoje["year"], $hoje["mon"], $hoje["mday"]); ?>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    <?php } ?>
<?php 

var_dump($_POST['arrachar']);


if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){ 
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox. 
    foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){ 
        $string = implode(' ', $selected); 
        print "<hr>". $string ."<hr>";

    } 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas tinha resolvido de outra forma...mas optei pela sua

Comment: ainda precisava de mais uma ajuda, pretendo que no calendário apareçam as checkbox já selecionadas de acordo com o que já foi inserido na tabela da base de dados.

Comment: ainda continuo sem conseguir resolver o problema do comentário acima, se puderes ajudar agradecia imenso

Comment: Aí você está montando todo o sistema só perguntando. Para você ver, está seria uma outra questão. Você tem que tentar desenvolver primeiro. Uma dica. Será preciso registrar na base o mês e o ano também. Depois, faz um SELECT, buscando pelo dia, mês e ano. Compara dentro do `for($day=1,$days_in_month=gmdate('t',$first_of_month); $day<=$days_in_month; $day++,$weekday++){` Aqui dentro você compara e adiciona o atributo HTML `checked`

Comment: para inserir o mês e o ano alterei esta linha `<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][dia]' value=$day> $day <br />` para `<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value=$year-$month-$day> $year-$month-$day  <br />`, pode ser desta forma?

Comment: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286555/checkbox-preenchida-com-dados-da-base-de-dados-em-php) , estou a tentar desta forma como mostro nesta pergunta, mas não está a funcionar. Podes ajudar me?

Comment: Você já fez uma pergunta sobre isso.
Seria interessante continuar suas dúvidas por lá. Em vez de comentar aqui, ou até lá mesmo, toda evolução que fizer edite sua questão. Melhorando sua pergunta, alguém pode entender e responder. No momento eu não estou podendo olhar. Mas Edite sua pergunta na questão que vc já fez, no link, edite lá.